# Azure ARM Template deployment of DataFactory with Azure DevOps Git configuration

Tags: git, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-data-factory, azure-deployment

I am attempting to deploy an Azure DataFactory resource and configure it to use Azure DevOps Git for source control. The Azure Devops organization, repository and collaboration branch all exist.

When I deploy the template, the DataFactory resource is created but it is not wired up to source control. My account has access to the Azure DevOps organization and I can manually wire up source control

I am using the following template:

```
{
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "variables": {
        "repoConfiguration": {
            "accountName": "my-account",
            "collaborationBranch": "dev",
            "lastCommitId": "",
            "projectName": "Azure",
            "repositoryName": "golaat",
            "rootFolder": "/",
            "tenantId": "",
            "type": "FactoryVSTSConfiguration"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories",
            "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
            "name": "my-resource-golaat8-adf",
            "location": "eastus2",
            "identity": {
              "type": "SystemAssigned"
            },
            "properties": {
              "repoConfiguration": "[variables('repoConfiguration')]"
            },
            "resources": []
          }
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the repoConfiguration from variables as following:

"repoConfiguration": "[variables('repoConfiguration')]"

Do not miss the Square Brackets. I tried at my side and got a success.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "name": {
            "defaultValue": "myv2datafactory",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "location": {
            "defaultValue": "East US",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "apiVersion": {
            "defaultValue": "2018-06-01",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "gitAccountName": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "gitRepositoryName": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "gitBranchName": {
            "defaultValue": "master",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "gitRootFolder": {
            "defaultValue": "/",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "gitProjectName": {
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "repoConfiguration": {
            "type": "FactoryVSTSConfiguration",
            "accountName": "[parameters('gitAccountName')]",
            "repositoryName": "[parameters('gitRepositoryName')]",
            "collaborationBranch": "[parameters('gitBranchName')]",
            "rootFolder": "[parameters('gitRootFolder')]",
            "projectName": "[parameters('gitProjectName')]"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories",
            "apiVersion": "[parameters('apiVersion')]",
            "name": "[parameters('name')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "identity": {
                "type": "SystemAssigned"
            },
            "properties": {
                "repoConfiguration": "[variables('repoConfiguration')]"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I corrected the missing square brackets around `[variables('repoConfiguration')]`; this was actually a typo in the sample code in the post and not my actual example. Can you confirm that your repository was actually wired up to source control by looking in the Azure Data Factory Author GUI? When I look at mine, it is not wired up at all.

Comment: @Jack Jia  I had similar query, and your answer works in one go. Thanks