# ADF Git Configure Disconnection After Publish with AzureResourceGroupDeployment & ARMTemplates

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I’m following the new CICD guide for ADF https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment-improvements

I am then publishing the ARMTemplates generated from the npm export pipeline to my **ADF Dev** using Azure Resource Group ARM Template deployment described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment#script

Looks like this:

```
- task: AzureResourceGroupDeployment@1
      displayName: 'Azure Deployment:Create Or Update Resource Group action on adf-dev-rg'
      inputs:
        ConnectedServiceName: 'guycarpenter-privatenonprod-Contributor'
        resourceGroupName: 'gc-adf-nasa-prinonprod-dev-rg'
        location: 'East US 2'
        csmFile: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/ARMTemplate/ARMTemplateForFactory.json'
        csmParametersFile: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/ARMTemplate/ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json'
```

After I publish the new ARMTemplate to my **ADF Dev**, ADF git repo Configure gets disconnected.
How should I publish the new ARMTemplate to my **ADF Dev** without disconnecting the repo?

Edit:
I also found that setting includeFactoryTemplate=false solves the disconenction, but I need it set to true to parametrize ADF for other environments.

Edit #2:
This solved the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56863897/13570809

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How should I publish the new ARMTemplate to my ADF Dev without disconnecting the repo?

There is a known user voice about this:

[Retain GIT configuration when deploying Data Factory ARM template](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/33625540-retain-git-configuration-when-deploying-data-facto)

You could vote this request and check the feedback.

And the Jason replied:

> This has been implemented by the repoConfiguration properties in the
> Azure Resource Manager template for the Data Factory resource. See
> here for reference -
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.datafactory/2018-06-01/factories

Comment: Thanks I also found that setting includeFactoryTemplate=false solves the disconenction, but I need it set to true to parametrize ADF for other environments.

Comment: I've tried adding your suggestion here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.datafactory/2018-06-01/factories to my Azure Template "ArmTemplateForFactory" but I get the following error: Invalid value for property 'type'".

I am using Azure DevOps Git type. I also dont see publishbranch option.

Comment: @ManriqueVargas, Have you checked this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56854139/azure-arm-template-deployment-of-datafactory-with-azure-devops-git-configuration, and how about use REST API to update the Configure Factory Repo: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/factories/configurefactoryrepo after AzureResourceGroupDeployment?