# Retain GitHub repository after Azure Data Factory pipeline deployment

Tags: github, azure-devops, azure-data-factory, continuous-deployment, cicd

## The project

I have an Azure Data Factory (ADF) pipeline that gets automatically deployed through an Azure DevOps CI/CD pipeline whenever some changes are detected.

[image: Azure DevOps pipeline]

## The problem

Whenever the deployment pipeline runs, the GitHub gets disconnected from ADF

The topic has been asked already in these two stackoverflow questions (that I know of):

- [ADF Git Configure Disconnection After Publish with AzureResourceGroupDeployment & ARMTemplates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67066574/7169710),
- [Azure ARM Template deployment of DataFactory with Azure DevOps Git configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56854139/7169710),

but I still cannot figure out where to add the `repoConfiguration` options (in the `arm-template-parameters-definition.json`? how?) so that when I publish from ADF, the `ARMTemplateForFactory.json` includes the `repoConfiguration` options.

## What I tried

I tried editing the `arm-template-parameters-definition.json` so that it includes something like the following (as per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.datafactory/2018-06-01/factories?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template) Microsoft Learn page):

```json
{
  "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories": {
    "properties": {
      "globalParameters": {
        "*": {
          "value": "="
        }
      },
      "globalConfigurations": {
        "*": "="
      },
      "encryption": {
        "*": "=",
        "identity": {
          "*": "="
        }
      },
      "repoConfiguration": {
        "accountName": "=",
        "repositoryName": "=",
        "collaborationBranch": "=",
        "rootFolder": "=",
        "clientId": "=",
        "clientSecret": {
          "byoaSecretAkvUrl": "=",
          "byoaSecretName": "="
        },
        "hostName": "="
      }
    },
    "location": "=",
    "identity": {
      "type": "=",
      "userAssignedIdentities": "="
    }
  }
}
```

No success, though. Is this a good approach? What else should I do?

## My last alternative

If nothing else works, my last alternative could be adding an [InvokeRESTAPI@1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/invoke-rest-api-v1?view=azure-pipelines&tabs=yaml) task in the Azure DevOps deployment pipeline to reconnect ADF to GitHub, since [Factories_ConfigureFactoryRepo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/factories/configure-factory-repo?tabs=HTTP) allows it. I do not like that much this alternative as it only bypasses the problem, but does not solve it.

```yaml
# Create a new task that runs an HTTP request that connects ADF to the GitHub repo
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/factories/configure-factory-repo?tabs=HTTP
- task: InvokeRESTAPI@1

  inputs:
    connectionType: 'AzureRM'
    azureSubscriptionEndpoint: 'MyAzureServiceConnection'
    method: 'POST'
    url: 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/************/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/locations/West Europe/configureFactoryRepo?api-version=2018-06-01'
    body: |
      {
        "factoryResourceId": "/subscriptions/************/resourceGroups/resource_name/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/data-factory-name",
        "repoConfiguration": {
          "type": "FactoryGitHubConfiguration",
          "accountName": "GitHubAccountName",
          "collaborationBranch": "main",
          "repositoryName": "GitHubRepoName",
          "rootFolder": "/",
          "clientId": "client-id",
          "clientSecret": "client-secret",
        }
      }
    contentType: 'application/json'
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not find much information on this; however, it looks like Microsoft only recommends you release to QA and Prod. Please review Current CI/CD flow here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery-improvements

I Did read a similar approach to your Solution #1 here: `[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56854139/azure-arm-template-deployment-of-datafactory-with-azure-devops-git-configuration/56863897#56863897][1]`