# Is there a way to change the collaboration branch of ADF without disconnecting from the Azure Git Repo?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I would like to change the collaboration branch on my Azure Data Factory to a different branch on which I have more control. My organization has restricted updates directly on the *master branch* (present collaboration branch). I do not wish to disconnect the existing repo and setup the GIT configuration again. Is there a simpler way to achieve this?

Update : I guess that my original concern of unable to merge code into the Collaboration branch correctly was an error from my side and I could merge correctly from a later stage. So this question is probably not needed. Thanks to everyone for the inputs.

Comment: Do you mean that you cannot Commit/Save directly to the master branch? This is our typical configuration: master/main is still the "collaboration branch", but we use individual branches for development and then PRs to merge to master/main.

Comment: @JoelCochran I cannot make any modifications directly on the master branch. I can merge changes into master using PRs but sometimes they just don't get merged correctly (especially in case of triggers) and this situation I have to update the triggers directly on the master (which is not possible due to restrictions)

Comment: Just to be clear, what it sounds like you are asking for is help circumventing your organization's code management policy. I would be more concerned with why the merges are not correct.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to change the collaboration branch of ADF without disconnecting from the Azure Git Repo?

If I understand you correct, you could implemented it by the repoConfiguration properties in the
Azure Resource Manager template for the Data Factory resource.

Check the reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.datafactory/2018-06-01/factories

```
"repoConfiguration": "[variables('repoConfiguration')]"
```

The template file:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "name": {
            "defaultValue": "myv2datafactory",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "location": {
            "defaultValue": "East US",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "apiVersion": {
            "defaultValue": "2018-06-01",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "gitAccountName": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "gitRepositoryName": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "gitBranchName": {
            "defaultValue": "master",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "gitRootFolder": {
            "defaultValue": "/",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "gitProjectName": {
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "repoConfiguration": {
            "type": "FactoryVSTSConfiguration",
            "accountName": "[parameters('gitAccountName')]",
            "repositoryName": "[parameters('gitRepositoryName')]",
            "collaborationBranch": "[parameters('gitBranchName')]",
            "rootFolder": "[parameters('gitRootFolder')]",
            "projectName": "[parameters('gitProjectName')]"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories",
            "apiVersion": "[parameters('apiVersion')]",
            "name": "[parameters('name')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "identity": {
                "type": "SystemAssigned"
            },
            "properties": {
                "repoConfiguration": "[variables('repoConfiguration')]"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Check the another thread:

[Azure ARM Template deployment of DataFactory with Azure DevOps Git configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56854139/azure-arm-template-deployment-of-datafactory-with-azure-devops-git-configuration/56863897#56863897)